# Regexp слово в кавычках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, как мне регулярку составить на C#, чтобы была последовательность из трех слов, причем последнне слово в кавычках.Например из строки надо однозначно выдернуть
**set vrouter "Trust-Gi"**
 у меня такой код, но регулярка в нем составлена неправильно..

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
            string pattern = @"set vrouter ".*"";
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    if (match.Success)
                        textBox1.AppendText(match.Value + '\n');
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых двойные ковычки нужно экранировать.
Во-вторых, если я правильно понял, то Вы хотите получить третье слово. Для этого лучше использовать группы. Вот рабочий пример:

```
string str = "set vrouter \"Trust-Gi\"";
string pattern = "set vrouter \"([^\"]+)\"";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
```

Далее получем значение. В паттерне то что в скобках - группа. У нас она одна. Но надо помнить что в группе с индеком `0` вся строка. Так что нас интересует 1-я:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

А по хорошему группы бы надо именовать:

```
string str = "set vrouter \"Trust-Gi\"";
string pattern = "set vrouter \"(?<myword>[^\"]+)\"";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
if (!match.Groups["myword"].Success)
{
   // Что-то пошло не так. Либо строка имеет другой формат, либо мы в регулрке не все учли

}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["myword"].Value);
}
```

`?<myword>` в шаблоне - как раз задание имени группы

А вообще, не поленитесь и почитайте про регулярные выражения и таких вопросов у Вас уже не будет возникать. [Тут](http://msgeeks.ru/?artid=47) доступно описаны основные моменты

Comment: Donil, спасибо за ответ!Сначала не понимал как приспособить ваши примеры в свой код.Но идея разделять на группы оказалась для меня прорывом.спасибо,что подвели к этому.Группы ,реально, нужны.

правда, регулярку поправил.не надо экранировать.
string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
но это уже эксперементально и дело техники...

Comment: @VitaliyLazarev, на здоровье!

P.S. "" - это тоже экранирование:)